# How to reference a variable in main method from a static class? (java)

Tags: java

For my program I have a static class which uses a Boolean statement. I would like to use this variable in my main in the instance of the user winning or losing the game.

However if I try to reference the variable it says it can not be found.

Here is a fraction of my code

```
    boolean playerWin;



    Dice.playerWin = false;
```

is there any reason why the symbol can not be found?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
    class Dice
    {

       static NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

       public static String playRound(double playerBet)
       {
            boolean playerWin;
            double amountWon = 0;
            if(playerWin = false)
            {
                Wallet.playerBalance -= playerBet; 

                amountWon = 0;

                return fmt.format(amountWon);  
            }
            else
            { 
                Wallet.playerBalance *= 2;

                amountWon = 1d/2d * Wallet.playerBalance;

                return fmt.format(amountWon);
            }
        }
```

and in the main class

```
    public class Game
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             String playerName;
             int playerBet;

             Dice die = new Dice();

             System.out.print("How much would you like to bet? ");
             while(playerBet != -1 && playerBet > 0)
             {
                  playerDie.roll();
                  playerDie2.roll();
                  computerDie.roll();
                  computerDie2.roll();
                  if(computerDie.equals(computerDie2));
                  {
                       System.out.print("Sorry you lost");

                       Dice.playerWin = false;
                  }

                  System.out.println();
                  System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on this round? ");
                  playerBet = in.nextInt();
```

The variable is in a static class and it is being used in the main method, what am I doing wrong?

Hopefully this extra bit helps.

Comment: Because it is not in scope. Show us the bigger picture.

Comment: is `playerWin` static?

Comment: try changing to public static boolean playerWin;

Comment: everything is accessed in a static way, that's a code smell.. Are you sure you want the `Wallet` to be shared amongs player?

Comment: public static boolean playerWin; also gives me an illegal start of expression error.

Comment: Edit and post all your code (each class in full)

Comment: I think you need to re-consider your code.  You seem to be trying to do an awful lot in that one method. Maybe a "Roll" class or something, with a win/lose property and an winAmount property, with respective getters and setters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Static class` is not same as `Static variable`.
A `static class` can only be an `nested class` and it only means that it can exist without `instance` of `parent class`.
A `static variable` is entirely different concept. You need to make your variable `static`, just having a `static class` is not sufficient.

Comment: "it can exist **without** instance"

Comment: I tried doing that too, but I keep getting illegal start of expression error!

Comment: in your edited code. Neither the class is static nor variable. So i am not sure if you have really created a static variable and calss.

Comment: @lokesh oh forgot to add in the edited code that the statements are part of a static method called playRound.

Comment: @FriarBob: My dear friend you can't reference a variable inside  a static method like this. I would strongly suggest to take agood java book and read about it. You can call that method directly but not its variable.

Comment: @Lokesh hmm well I am learning, I will try looking into other means, thanks.

Comment: A static class is not the same as an inner class.  Nested classes can either be static or "inner" (i.e. non static), but not both.